# Need to get the Products Standard Salesforce Object added to SFMC Data Stream

Tags: sales-cloud, marketing-cloud

You know this is a good one because it's almost Christmas Eve, but I'm driving myself crazy here.

I have a **Salesforce Marketing Clou**d account that is using the **V5 Salesforce Connector**.

Everything seems to be configured correctly, but there's a field I need to get to from the **Products Object**.  The Products Object doesn't show up in the Contact Builder as and Available Entity.  There are 112 other Objects, but I can't find the one I want.

I've poured through more online resources than I care to mention, but I'm totally stuck here.

**Any ideas?**  Happy to look up **details of the config**, and I'm pretty new to **Salesforce Sales Cloud**, so apologies if this is so glaringly obvious that it's not documented.

Thanks!
-Aaron

Comment: try checking the object and FLS for that specific profile if logged in user is having proper access. In case you are using connector then make sure the connector user profile is having proper access

Comment: I'm gonna do my best to figure out what that means and then go from there!  Is it possible to limit visibility to a specific object, and if so--where can I see that setting?

Comment: Yes..through profiles you can do that. You need to find the user record first and then try to find out related profile in which you will find all necessary permssions of Field level security and object level

Comment: Everything looks good--All users are System Administrators, and have visibility to the Product Object.  Still Stumped!  Surely this is possible.

Comment: Is the marketing user a different user or the logged in user only?

Comment: The SF user with the API Connection to SFMC is a system administrator profile in SF.  The API User in SFMC has all the correct privileges too.  Is is possible that it is just not possible to sync the products object to SFMC?